# Converting PST time to Local device time in android

Tags: android, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert PST time to Device local time using below function. It works fine but in London timezone its not working properly. If its 04:58 AM PST then it should show 12:58 PM as per London timezone but its showing 12:58 AM. Am i doing anything wrong here? Please kindly guide.

```
System.out.println("2015-06-23 04:58:00 AM = "
                + getFormattedTimehhmm(new TimeTest()
                        .getTimeRelativeToDevice("2015-06-23 04:58:00 AM")));

public String getTimeRelativeToDevice(String pstTime) {
        final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);

        TimeZone fromTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");

        TimeZone toTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");

        // Get a Calendar instance using the default time zone and locale.
        Calendar fromCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Set the calendar's time with the given date
        fromCalendar.setTimeZone(fromTimeZone);
        try {
            fromCalendar.setTime(sdf.parse(pstTime));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Input: " + fromCalendar.getTime() + " in "
                + fromTimeZone.getDisplayName());    
        return sdf.format(fromCalendar.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing all the time zone stuff yourself? Just call `fromCalendar.setTimeZone(toTimeZone)`...

Comment: I am doing fromCalendar.setTimezone in code. The issue is its not properly converting time for all. Sometime it works really good, but in some timezone like London its not working properly.

Comment: Ah, so you are - in which case why are you *also* manually doing conversion? Note that you haven't specified the time zone for the `SimpleDateFormat`. In fact, that's *all* you need to do... I've added an answer; if that doesn't work, please give an example - ideally in a short but complete program that also fails on the desktop. (If this is an Android-specific problem, that would be good to know...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Moritz that using Joda Time would make the code simpler, but you should be able to do all of this *much* more simply than your current approach:

```
public String getTimeRelativeToDevice(String pstTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));

    Date parsed = sdf.parse(pstTime);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    return sdf.format(parsed);
}
```

Currently you're doing all kinds of messing around, but never specifying the time zone of the `SimpleDateFormat`, which is the important part...

Answer (score 0):

You should use jodatime. It greatly simpliefies the time zone conversion. For example:

```
new LocalDateTime(timestamp.getTime()).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```